# How to adjust alpha value of UINavigationBar's backgroundImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I set navigationBar's `backgroundImage` with this code.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:self.titleBar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And I want to make image's alpha value changed, when I scroll down & up. So I use the changing the alpha value of `UIImage` method like:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByApplyingAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

But it doesn't works well. How can I change the alpha value of navigationBar's backgroundImage?

Comment: @northpenfuin hi this ilke may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460209/change-the-alpha-value-of-the-navigation-bar