# How can I set alpha to the navbar but except children (Back button, title etc.)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have to set alpha to the navbar, and I do it by `self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.2f;`

The problem is that buttons and title have alpha as the navbar.

I understand the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460209/change-the-alpha-value-of-the-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 1):

You could set your navigation bar's background color to something like [`[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.2];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithWhite:alpha:) or use [`[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)

Comment: thanks for your feedback. `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2f];` doesn't apply alpha :( only the color