# Change UINavigationBar alpha to 0, then back home and return to app. the navigationBar alpha change to 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

First. set alpha = 0.

[image]

click HOME back to backgroud, then click app back to app. 
The alpha will set 1 auto automaticly.

[image]

How to set the navigationBar alpha = 0 forever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17542389/6271729 tried this?

Comment: UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:  has the same question. I test

Comment: remove navigation bar from storyboard itself(just go to storyboard uncheck show navigation bar in navigation bar controller screen

Answer (score 0):

If you want programatically try this:

If you want no navigation bar, and you want the content to be adjusted up  to where the navigation bar normally would be, you should use

```
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Otherwise use self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES; gives you a space where the navigationBar is.

Answer (score 0):

**when you come back from second view controller to first view controller then you have to implement some code in viewWillAppear method :**

**code**

**viewController1**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:YES];
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

**viewController2**

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```